# Discord bot not dming, while having all of the intents on

Tags: discord.js

I have a discord bot that is supposed to DM the user anytime they have a moderator action against them. (Getting muted, etc.)
**DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions**

I have all of the intents on for the bot and it is only in 2 servers.

[Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CaFy.png)

This is the code I use to DM, it is in typescript but I basicly use discord.JS documentation and that while writing it due to its simularities.

```
 try {
        await user.createDM()
        await user.send(`You have been muted for ${reason!}! It will last ${time!} minutes!`)
      } catch (error) {
        await interaction.reply({
            content: `The player was not DMed!`,
            ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
```

Comment: I just relised that I forgot to remove part of the script not shown from the orginial script it was copied from.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I just relised that I forgot to remove part of the script not shown from the orginial script it was copied from.

Comment: Unless this answered your problem this should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: It fixed my problem, so i put it as a awnser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tested it and it fixed it.... There's no need for others to confirm my answer.